# Catch all unhandled C# exceptions when using edge.js

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

Edge.js allows us to call into C# dlls from node.js.  Because of this, we have many entry points into our dlls.  I would like to catch all unhandled exceptions so that I can log them properly then rethrow them back out to node.js (where they're dealt with).  Is this possible?

With a UI-less application, I would typically do this via:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

Unfortunately the `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` handler is never hit when an exception is called.

**Update with more info:**

Here's essentially what the C# code boils down to for this test:

```
static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  Logger.Error("Unhandled Exception caught - rethrown.", (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
  throw (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
}

public async Task<object> ExceptionTest(object input)
{
  return await Task.Run<object>(() =>
  {
    Logger.Error("Test to verify logging");
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    throw new Exception("Test Exception");
    return null;
  });
}
```

The node.js server is started and calls ExceptionTest through edge.js.  In the debugger, a breakpoint in `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` is not hit, outside of a debugger nothing is logged from that method, "Test to verify logging" is logged as expected.

Comment: How do you know that an exception occured? Did you catch it somewhere in your code? If so, a caught exception will not trigger an invocation of *UnhandledException*, unless you re-throw it.

Comment: For my test cases, Im calling a method where I'm explicitly throwing an Exception in order to try this.

Comment: Ok, then you will need to trouble-shoot some more - your question is too brief and does not contain any information that would help anyone understanding your code... Just a shot in the dark: Verify that you throw your exception in the same ApplicationDomain that was current when your code did `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;`.

Comment: Question updated with some more information.  Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you await *ExceptionTest* (which is *async*)? If not, you might want to [read here](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/01/technical/handling-unhandled-exceptions-with-asyncawait-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/), for example...

Comment: ExceptionTest is awaited by edge.js, that happens internally inside that package.  From my point of view, there is no C# code before ExceptionTest, it gets called directly from node.js.  From your link, I also tried setting TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, but to no avail.

Comment: I don't know too much about Edge.js, but it's documentation (*"CLR exceptions thrown in .NET code invoked from Node.js are marshalled as the error parameter to the Node.js callback function"*) sounds like it catches exceptions (how else would it be able to marshall exception information) - which would explain why the UnhandledException handler is not invoked...

Comment: Yes, just read that myself.  Thanks for your help.